# awk syntax and string error

Tags: linux, bash, syntax, awk

I am currently trying to add a new string on the beginning of each line in a text file (temp.txt) and make a new file with combined text (newtemp.txt) using `awk`.

My code is:

```
awk  " NR>1{printf \"=HYPERLINK(B%d, C%d) "\t" https://otrs.city.pittsburgh.pa.us/index.pl?Action=AgentTicketZoom;TicketID=%s\n\", NR-1, NR-1, $0}" temp.txt > untemp.txt
```

It is making a new file called untemp.txt that only has the string. 
EX:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
=HYPERLINK(B2, C2)  https://otrs.city.pittsburgh.pa.us/index.pl?Action=AgentTicketZoom;TicketID=
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
=HYPERLINK(B3, C3)  https://otrs.city.pittsburgh.pa.us/index.pl?Action=AgentTicketZoom;TicketID=
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
=HYPERLINK(B4, C4)  https://otrs.city.pittsburgh.pa.us/index.pl?Action=AgentTicketZoom;TicketID=
etc...
```

I want it to add the string above at the beginning of every line in the temp.txt.
It works in gawk but not awk.
What is the correct syntax, I am using Linux shell.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: +1 for apparently trying to manipulate spreadsheets with awk.

Comment: `awk  ' NR>1{printf "=HYPERLINK(B%d, C%d) \t https://otrs.confidental/index.pl?Action=AgentTicketZoom;TicketID=%s\n", NR-1, NR-1, $0} ' temp.txt > newtemp.txt` worked for me on Mac

Comment: Yup, and it worked for me in gawk(windows GNU shell) but not awk (Linux shell) I edited the form, tell me if it works now and reread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your original string,

```
" NR>1{printf \"=HYPERLINK(B%d, C%d) "\t" https://otrs.city.pittsburgh.pa.us/index.pl?Action=AgentTicketZoom;TicketID=%s\n\", NR-1, NR-1, $0}"
```

, would work as an `awk` program in *any* (Bourne-like) shell:

**Your string is composed of 3 separate strings** joined to form a single string:

- **Part 1**: `" NR>1{printf \"=HYPERLINK(B%d, C%d) "`

  - This part will *happens* to be passed through to `awk` unmodified - see part 3 below.
- **Part 2**: `\t` is an *unquoted* string that does NOT represent a  char; instead, the shell interprets this as **just `t`** (it "eats" the `\`), and only `t` gets appended to part 1.
- **Part 3**: `" https://otrs.city.pittsburgh.pa.us/index.pl?Action=AgentTicketZoom;TicketID=%s\n\", NR-1, NR-1, $0}"` - due to using *double* quotes - is expanded by the *shell* first, so before `awk` even sees the string, the shell expands `$0` to *its* definition of that token (loosely speaking, the shell executable in an interactive shell, the script filename in a script).

When run from an interactive (non-login) `bash` shell, this is what `awk` would see (broken into multiple lines just for readability - note the lone `t` and `bash` in lieu of `$0`):

```
 NR>1{printf "=HYPERLINK(B%d, C%d) t 
 https://otrs.city.pittsburgh.pa.us/index.pl?Action=AgentTicketZoom;TicketID=%s\n", 
 NR-1, NR-1, bash}
```

Clearly not what you had intended.

---

The fix, as already posted in a comment by @GolgiDevang, is to **use *single* quotes around the entire string, which is generally the best choice for `awk` programs**:

- It prevents the *shell* from applying undesired expansions before the string is passed to `awk`.

  - With double quotes, the potential for confusion is great, because `$`-prefixed tokens have meaning both in the shell and in `awk`.
  - If you do need to pass *shell* variables for use inside an `awk` program, use the `-v` option; e.g.: `-v var="$var"` - this defines *awk* variable `var` with value of *shell* variable `$var`
- It allows you to use `"` without escaping (and if you do need to escape *nested* double quotes `awk`'s sake, use `\"`).

Thus (did you mean to surround the  with a space each?):

```
awk 'NR>1{printf "=HYPERLINK(B%d, C%d) \t https://otrs.city.pittsburgh.pa.us/index.pl?Action=AgentTicketZoom;TicketID=%s\n", NR-1, NR-1, $0}' temp.txt > untemp.txt
```